# Export UTM coordinates with sub-meter precision from a shapefile in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, pathfinder, calculate-geometry, precision-scale

I have a series of points in ArcGIS Pro that were collected with sub-meter precision. I need to export UTM coordinates for each point so that I can use them for some processing outside of Arc, and I need them to be accurate to 2 decimal places to be consistent with my other data.  I tried using the Calculate Geometry Attributes tool, but the coordinates it outputs are rounded up to meters (and yes, I have set the display in the attribute table to show the correct number of decimal places).

Is it that Calculate Geometry doesn't calculate outputs to that level of precision?  If so, what tool should I use instead (I can do some basic Python, if necessary).

Or... is there something wrong with my underlying data?  I collected the data with a Trimble GeoExplorer handheld (can't remember the exact model), did a differential correction with Pathfinder office, brought the output shapefile directly into Arc, and then projected and transformed it from WGS84 Lat/Long to NAD83 UTM 10N. Is there a step in there that could have truncated my coordinate values?  I'm new to working with data at this level of precision.

Comment: What is the x,y resolution of your dataset? In which field type are the fields where you calculated the geometry?

Comment: You should make sure that your fields have been created such that they are 'float' type and have sufficient precision and scale to support the numbers you want to store https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/arcgis-field-data-types.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out I just needed to switch the field type from float to double.  UTM coordinates are too long to be stored using float (when I looked more closely, my northings were being rounded off to 10m).  Thank you @FSimardGIS - you were on the right track.